# Passing in a Func to Where and using IQueryable

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework and am building up a `IQueryable<T>`

```
IQueryable<Message> query = db.Messages;

query = query.OrderByDescending(m => m.Created);
query = query.Where(m => m.Deleted == false);

if (lastTime != null)
    query = query.Where(m => m.Created < lastTime);

var func = ExpressionHelper.GetPredicate(stream);

query = query.Where(func).AsQueryable; *** ISSUE HERE?? ***

query = query.Skip(skip)
          .Take(count)
          .Include(m => m.Tags)
          .Include(m => m.Properties);

var results = query.ToList();
```

The issue is the Tags and Properties are not populated in the final list.

I believe it has something to do with the `Func<>` I am passing in and also believe that after it although `AsQueryable` is used it doesn't represent `IQueryable` or does no longer connect to the database.

Is there a way to get Tags and Properties populated?

I'm not sure if making the `Func<>` to be `Expression<Func<>>` would help and if so is there a way to convert the below to be `Expression<Func<>>`

**UPDATE:**

```
public static Func<Message, bool> GetPredicate(string expression)
{
    Func<Message, bool> result = null;

    try
    {
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Classes.Message), "Message");
        var lambda = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { parameter }, null, expression);
        result = lambda.Compile() as Func<Message, bool>;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.Fatal(e);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Using `Func<...>` will force it into LINQ-to-Objects, rather than using query composition at the EF level. I strongly suggest seeing what happens when you try `Expression<Func<...>>`.

Comment: I think converting to `Expression` would help, but there is no way of telling you how to do that unless you show us the code for `GetPredicate()`.

Comment: If you're working with an IQueryable, you should be passing an Expression<Func<>>, not a Func<>. I'd gladly help you "convert the below to be Expression<Func<>>" if there was anything below...

Comment: Did you omit "the below" example from your last line?

Comment: DOH! Question updated!

Comment: @Jon in that case, that should just be a "cast" away; i.e. `return (Expression<Func<Message,bool>>)lambda;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At this point here:

```
query.Where(func) // where func is Func<...>
```

you have switched into LINQ-to-Objects. Anything you do after than (in terms of `.Include` etc) **is irrelevant** - you are no longer composing an EF query. You have a thin `IQueryable<T>` wrapper over a LINQ-to-Objects version of the sequence **as it was at that line**, i.e.

```
query = query.Where(func).AsQueryable(); // this is just a thing veneer over L2O
```

Switching to `Expression<Func<...>>` is likely to help.

If you absolutely positively can't generate an `Expression`, you could move the `Include` etc *above* this point.

Comment: @Jon note: that is only a "if you can't get an `Expression`" workaround. It would be better (more efficient, less bandwidth, etc) to use an `Expression` predicate so that the complete query can be composed

Comment: OK thanks. The issue I think I have is that the GetPredicate method is using methods and properties not mapped on the database and this is throwing exceptions if using Expression<>

Comment: Does that mean using a Func<> and not Expression<> doesnt execute against the database?

Comment: The EF internals have to be able to pull the Expression<Func<>> apart to convert it into the SQL equivalent; that's not possible with a Func<>, which is just a delegate.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't actually wired this in so it may be slightly off, but as Marc says you've swapped into Linq to Objects at the AsQueryable.

If you remove that call, and then switch the GetPredicate to below it should work. It's the same except that we don't need to compile the lambda, this will happen when the query reaches entity framework.

```
public static Expression<Func<Message, bool>> GetPredicate(string expression)
{
    Expression<Func<Message, bool>> result = null;

    try
    {
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Classes.Message), "Message");
        var lambda = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { parameter }, null, expression);
        result = (Expression<Func<Message, bool>>)lambda;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.Fatal(e);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: The issue I think I have is that the GetPredicate method is using methods and properties not mapped on the database and this is throwing exceptions if using Expression<>

Comment: Can you include the implementation of ParseLambda? We may be able to make some tweaks and have it work still...